# How to Retrieve data in the interval of every 5 sec from the database

Tags: vb.net

Data in the database is stored in every one second.  In a day around 30,000 data is stored. We have 5 column in which 1st column is time where every second the time is stored and rest four columns are numeric values. We are able to fetch all the the data for a particular date and display it in the datagridview. But this is a huge data. Can we write a query where data is retrieved in the interval of every 5 or 10 seconds?

Thanks [Data stored in the database and the result required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQjeu.jpg)

Comment: You could always use a timer?

Comment: can you use WHERE time LIKE '%0' OR time LIKE '%5'?

Comment: Thanks peterG with you suggestion I was able to retrieve the data points in the interval of 5 sec. Thank one again for you post.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your info is quite small.

What you can do is to call your query every 5 seconds.

For this you could use a thread out of the threadpool and use a Thread.Sleep to wait.

This could look like this:

```
Private Async Sub Doit() 
Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
While(True)
'Your code
Thread.Sleep(5000) ' because 1000milliseconds = 1 second
End While
End Sub)

End Sub
```

I'm sorry but I do not know what your query actually looks like
and I do not know which database you're talking about.

Comment: We are using SQL 2008. Data is already stored in every second only thing we have to do is retives the data every 5th second rather than every second. I have posted the jpg file where i have shown how the data is stored and what results is expected. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

where convert(date,[System1_Date_Time])='2015-02-26' and (CONVERT(time,E_Gun_Mod_Date_Time) like '%%:%%:%5.%%%%' or CONVERT(time,E_Gun_Mod_Date_Time) like '%%:%%:%0.%%%%')